# Using angular-modal-service without using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement a modal service in my angular app. Now for that I am using Angular-modal-service (http://www.dwmkerr.com/the-only-angularjs-modal-service-youll-ever-need/).

The blog says that we can implement the modal without the bootstrap, but there is no example.
Any help ?

Now I tried it with bootstrap also. But no luck so far.
Here is my controller

```
require([
    'services/abcService',
    'angular-services/angular-modal-service',
    'libraries/bootstrap'
], function (app) {
    "use strict";

    abcController.$inject = ['angularModalService'];

    function abcController(abcService, ModalService) {
        var self = this;

        abcService.getData().success(function (data) {
            self.names = data.names;
        });

        self.show = function () {
            ModalService.showModal({
                templateUrl: 'abc.html',
                controller: 'pqrController'
            }).then(function (modal) {
                modal.element.modal();
                modal.close.then(function () {
                    console.log("hey  !");
                });
            });
        };
    };

    app.controller('abcController', abcController);

});
```

And here is the pqrController

```
require([
    'angular-services/angular-modal-service'
], function (app) {
    "use strict";

    function pqrController(close) {
        this.close = function (result) {
            close(result, 500);
        };
    };

    app.controller('pqrController', pqrController);

});
```

Now when I invoke the show() function from the controller 1, I get the html of the modal on the bottom of the screen. Instead it should show as a modal, over the screen.

Comment: That same blog shows some code examples on custom modal [here](http://dwmkerr.github.io/angular-modal-service/) (scroll to the last example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the modal works is by putting some classes on the element that you want to show as a modal; then, the CSS works with those classes to cause the element to display in the way you want it to. It sounds like you've still got the classes going onto the elements, but no CSS to put it where you want. I would suggest taking inspiration from the bootstrap sources to work out how to make CSS that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks ! That was exactly the case. i wasn't using any css.